# How to maintain/access textbox values across postbacks which are set by Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am looking for a way to maintain the `GridView TextBox` values which are set by jQuery across postbacks. I searched a lot on Google but could not find a solution.

```
function CalculateTaxes() {
    var taxvaluesum = 0;
    $(".taxvalue").each(function () {
        //add only if the value is number               

        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            taxvaluesum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
        else {
            $(this).val('0')
        }
    });
    //$('.totaltaxvalue').val(taxvaluesum.toFixed(2));
    $('.totaltaxvalue').attr("value", taxvaluesum.toFixed(2));
    var finalamt = parseFloat($('.totaltaxvalue').val()) + parseFloat($('#ContentPlaceHolder1_Gridview1_txtftrvalue').val());
    $('.finalamount').attr("value", finalamt.toFixed(2));
    //$('.finalamount').val(finalamt.toFixed(2));
}    

$(document).on('blur', ".taxvalue", function (e) {
    CalculateTaxes();
    var roundedvalue =parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2);
    $(this).val(roundedvalue);

    $(this).siblings('input[type="hidden"]').val(roundedvalue);
    alert($(this).siblings('input[type="hidden"]').val());                   
});
```

Comment: Are you saying that your hidden fields definitely have some value at the point the postback occurs but that those values are not reaching the server? I put values into hidden fields using javascript on almost every page (usually to record the current scroll position of divs) and the data is always there when posted back.

Comment: YES ! that is what I am saying. I have value in hiddenfield but its not reaching server.

Comment: What happens if you write the data into a visible text box when, say, clicking a button? Is the value definitely getting written to the control? What happens if you click a submit button then? Does it reach the server? Do you have ViewState disabled?

Comment: as you can see in the last line of my code I have an alert to check value of Hidden field which I set value of on textbox onblur event and it gives me the value. So in short.. Hiddenfield has the value but when I click a button I get "" in codebehind for that control. ViewState is not disabled since other fields on the form are retaining value.

Comment: Is the hidden field dynamically created?

Comment: It is in GridView, so I yes.

Answer (score 0):

I once faced similar issue, retrieving value directly like hdnElement.Value was always empty on post back. The below worked for me.

```
Request.Form(hdnElement.UniqueID))
```